# How do I get wepback to get a static file ready to be used as an import?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-modules

I have a single `.js` file that has a lot of `export const` functions in there. Unfortunately, that file needs to be loaded by the back-end and added directly via an `<src>` tag. This means I need to transpile it and make it work before importing it. So, there's no `yarn add` to put it through the transpilation process of my project and, of course, these functions will have to be global.

How can I make this work? I've tried to just simply run it through the Babel REPL but I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined` no matter the configuration.

How to solve this?

Comment: are you able to import this file later/not?

Comment: @tyskr As of now, I think not. The back-end simply puts this file in the `src` and is done with it. It then exists in the global name-space, so, from within my project, I can only call the function names from there. So, assuming I needed to use function `A` from that file inside my project, I'd just call it `A()`. It sucks, but it's how it is.

Comment: hi, so we could probably do this. webpack the file offline, upload it to your server (which would serve I guess) and mark the `script` tag a module. Then you must be able to use all the constants in there.